# CodeSignature aspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

What is the CodeSignature in aspectJ? I tried to find [JavaDocs](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/reflect/CodeSignature.html) but didn't find anything useful. For Instance, thy is the following signature is a CodeSignature:

```
pointcut log() : execution(@Log * *(..));

before() : log() {
    String[] names = ((CodeSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).getParameterNames();
}
```

Is there a JoinPoint such that `thisJoinPoint.getSignature()` that is not a `CodeSignature`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeSignature represents a code block captured by a join point. It may be a method, constructor, initializer (static or non-static) or an advise.  There are join points where the signature is not a `CodeSignature`. For example join points for field set and field get where the signature is a [FieldSignature](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/reflect/FieldSignature.html) and join point for a catch clause has a [CatchClauseSignature](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/reflect/CatchClauseSignature.html).

Signatures provide access to information on which join point is called upon.